# Is there any limit on bootstrap action on Amazon EMR?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am using shell script to do some manipulation on my data. Which takes more than 1 hour. But everytime it crosses one hour limit. My bootstrap action gets failed. Did anyone notice this thing or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 45mn limit on bootstrapping tasks, according to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64568:

"...The timeout for bootstrapping is 45 minutes and all the bootstrap actions put together should complete in that period."